# Applying conditions to the whole vector

Tags: c++, c++03

I need to have a while loop that applies a logic condition to every element of a vector.

For example, while(all elements < 3) or  while(all elements != 3)

The only way I can think of is write while(vector[1]!=3 || vector[2]!=3 || ...). That would quickly grow if my vector is large.

Are there better way of doing this in C++?

Comment: If you're making this check frequently, you might want to look into some alternatives, such as keeping the vector sorted at all times, or keeping track of the max element of the vector. That would make this check O(1) instead of O(N).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [`std::all_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)

Assuming

`std::vector<int> v;`

```
if(std::all_of(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), [](int i){ return i < 3 }))
{

}

if(std::all_of(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), [](int i){ return i != 3 }))
{

}
```

Pre-C++11

```
struct Check
{
    int d;
    Check(int n) : d(n) {}
    bool operator()(int n) const 
    { return n < d; }
};

// Copied from above link

template< class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate >
bool all_of(InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate p)
{
   for (; first != last; ++first) {
        if (!p(*first)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true ;
}


if( all_of(v.begin(), v.end(), Check(3) ))
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was going to ask for pre C++11.

Comment: @holianoify & Galik didn't remember sorry, copied the template implemenation

Comment: @holianoify In general you should specify if you are restricted to a particular version of C++. There is a `C++03` tag, which you should also use in this case.

Comment: @holianoify In C++03, you could also use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), searching for  the first element that does not satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11, the answer is essentially using `std::all` together with lambdas:

if (std::all(v.begin(),v.end(),[](const typename std::decay::type& a)
{ return a<3; })
{  7* your stuff here */ }

In C++03, you have to workout std::all and the lambdas:

```
template<class Iter, Fn>
bool all(Iter i, Iter end, Fn fn)
{
   for(;i!=end; ++i) 
     if(!fn(*i)) return false;
   return true;
}
```

and for `<3` you need an explicit class like

```
class is_less_than_val
{
   int val;
public:
   is_less_than(int value) :val(value) {}

   bool operator()(int var) const { return var<val; }
};
```

so that you can write

```
if(all(v.begin(),v.end(),is_less_than_val(3))
{ /* your stuff here */ }
```

---

In case you find all the functinal machinery obscure (C++03 is not that "easy", having no substantial type deduction), and prefer a more procedural approach,

```
template<class Cont, class Val>
bool all_less_than(const Cont& c, const Val& v)
{
   for(typename Cont::const_iterator i=c.cbegin(), i!=c.end(); ++i)
      if(!(*i < v)) return false;
   return true;
}

template<class Cont, class Val>
bool all_equal_to(const Cont& c, const Val& v)
{
   for(typename Cont::const_iterator i=c.cbegin(), i!=c.end(); ++i)
      if(!(*i == v)) return false;
   return true;
}
```

In all the samples, whatever the code is arranged, everything boils down into a loop that breaks as false on the negation of the searched condition.

Of course, if all are numerical comparison, `!(<)` is `>=` and `!(==)` is `!=`, but since Cont and Val are template parameters, using only < and == result is less requirements for Val implementation (that can be anything, not just `int`)

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, in C++11, there are special functions for
this.  In pre-C++11, the usual idiom would have involved
`std::find_if`, and a comparison with the end iterator on the
results, e.g.:

```
struct Condition
{
    //  The condition here must be inversed, since we're looking for elements
    //  which don't meet it.
    bool operator()( int value ) const { return !(value < 3); }
};

//  ...
while ( std::find_if( v.begin(), v.end(), Condition() ) == v.end() ) {
    //  ...
}
```

This is such a common idiom that I continue to use it in C++11
(although often with a lambda).